# How to iterate following strings in python dynamically or by taking input from user?

Tags: python, loops, logic

here's the problem:

```
number_of_batches = 8
number_of_dishes = 6

batch_names = batch_1 , batch_2, batch_3,batch_4, batch_5, batch_6, batch_7,batch_8
dish_names = dish_1, dish_2, dish_3, dish_4, dish_5, dish_6
```

expected output:

```
batch_1: dish_1, dish_2, dish_3, dish_4, dish_5, dish_6
batch_2: dish_2, dish_3, dish_4, dish_5, dish_6, dish_1
batch_3: dish_3, dish_4, dish_5, dish_6, dish_1, dish_2
batch_4: dish_4, dish_5, dish_6, dish_1, dish_2, dish_3
batch_5: dish_5, dish_6, dish_1, dish_2, dish_3, dish_4
batch_6: dish_6, dish_1, dish_2, dish_3, dish_4, dish_5
batch_7: dish_1, dish_2, dish_3, dish_4, dish_5, dish_6
batch_8: dish_2, dish_3, dish_4, dish_5, dish_6, dish_1
```

Comment: Are the batch names "strings" ? is a list ? Because as we see your code they are variablesn and the output is unclear

Answer (score 0):

If all are strings, use a `deque` to get the nice `rotate` method

```
from collections import deque

number_of_batches = 8
number_of_dishes = 6
batches = [f"batch_{i + 1}" for i in range(number_of_batches)]
dishes = deque(f"dish_{i + 1}" for i in range(number_of_dishes))

for batch in batches:
    print(batch, ":", *dishes)
    dishes.rotate(-1)
```

```
batch_1 : dish_1 dish_2 dish_3 dish_4 dish_5 dish_6
batch_2 : dish_6 dish_1 dish_2 dish_3 dish_4 dish_5
batch_3 : dish_5 dish_6 dish_1 dish_2 dish_3 dish_4
batch_4 : dish_4 dish_5 dish_6 dish_1 dish_2 dish_3
batch_5 : dish_3 dish_4 dish_5 dish_6 dish_1 dish_2
batch_6 : dish_2 dish_3 dish_4 dish_5 dish_6 dish_1
batch_7 : dish_1 dish_2 dish_3 dish_4 dish_5 dish_6
batch_8 : dish_6 dish_1 dish_2 dish_3 dish_4 dish_5
```

Comment: can't we rotate it serial-wise? or any other way to rotate it serial-wise?
like 
123456
234561
Such like that?

Comment: as you have suggested, the batch is rotating randomly, right? so can't we make it serial-wise?

Comment: @SagarNakade it can, with `-1` as parameter, see my edit

Comment: yes! it is working very fine. Thank you so much!